# Boto: uploading multiple files to s3

Tags: python, angular, amazon-s3, boto, bitbucket-pipelines

I am a JavaScript/Angular 2 developer who is now getting involved with deployment using Bitbucket pipelines, Python and Boto for s3 integration. I was only introduced to these three technologies yesterday!

My webpack build produces a folder, `dist`, that contains all of the files I would like to upload to s3. I would like these files to appear in the root of the s3 bucket.

I have the following in my `bitbucket-pipelines.yaml`:

```
image: node:5.6.0

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          # other stuff..,
          - python s3_upload.py io-master.mycompany.co.uk dist io-dist
```

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/awslabs/amazon-s3-bitbucket-pipelines-python/src/d1a2cd2355813b62621d8fedc9e100acf9adb228/s3_upload.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) is the entire Python `s3_upload.py`

As you can see, the script uses `put_object`:

```
client.put_object(
    Body=open(artefact, 'rb'),
    Bucket=bucket,
    Key=bucket_key
)
```

What I would like to be able to do is upload the contents of the `dist` folder to s3. Do I have to learn Python in order to be able to do this, or is there a method in Boto to do this already?

Answer (score 3):

```
def sync_to_s3(target_dir, aws_region=AWS_REGION, bucket_name=BUCKET_NAME):
    if not os.path.isdir(target_dir):
        raise ValueError('target_dir %r not found.' % target_dir)

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name=aws_region)
    try:
        s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name,
                         CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': aws_region})
    except ClientError:
        pass

    for filename in os.listdir(target_dir):
        logger.warn('Uploading %s to Amazon S3 bucket %s' % (filename, bucket_name))
        s3.Object(bucket_name, filename).put(Body=open(os.path.join(target_dir, filename), 'rb'))

        logger.info('File uploaded to https://s3.%s.amazonaws.com/%s/%s' % (
            aws_region, bucket_name, filename))
```

you can pass a folder as argument and iterate files